# Why gsutil restore a file from a bucket encrypted with KMS (using a service account without DECRYPT permission)?

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I am working with GCP KMS, and it seems that when I send a file to a GCP bucket (using gustil cp) it is encrypted.

However, I have a question related to the permission to restore that file from the same bucket, using a different service account. I mean, the service account that I am using to restore the file from the bucket, doesn't have Decrypt privilege and even so the gustil cp works.

My question is whether it's normal behavior, or if I'm missing something ?

Let me describe my question:

1. First of all, I confirm that the default encryption for the bucket is the KEY that I set up previously:

   ```
   $ kms encryption gs://my-bucket

   Default encryption key for gs://my-bucket:
   projects/my-kms-project/locations/my-location/keyRings/my-keyring/cryptoKeys/MY-KEY
   ```
2. Next, with gcloud config, I set a service account, which has  "Storage Object Creator" and "Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter" permissions:

   ```
   $ gcloud config set account my-service-account-with-Encrypter-and-object-creator-permissions
   Updated property [core/account].
   ```
3. I send a local file to the bucket:

   ```
   $ gsutil cp my-file gs://my-bucket

   Copying file://my-file [Content-Type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation]...
   | [1 files][602.5 KiB/602.5 KiB]
   Operation completed over 1 objects/602.5 KiB.
   ```

   After sending the file to the bucket, I confirm that the file is encrypted using the KMS key I created before:

   ```
   $ gsutil ls -L gs://my-bucket

   gs://my-bucket/my-file:
       Creation time:          Mon, 25 Mar 2019 06:41:02 GMT
       Update time:            Mon, 25 Mar 2019 06:41:02 GMT
       Storage class:          REGIONAL
       KMS key:                projects/my-kms-project/locations/my-location/keyRings/my-keyring/cryptoKeys/MY-KEY/cryptoKeyVersions/1
       Content-Language:       en
       Content-Length:         616959
       Content-Type:           application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
       Hash (crc32c):          8VXRTU==
       Hash (md5):             fhfhfhfhfhfhfhf==
       ETag:                   xvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvx=
       Generation:             876868686868686
       Metageneration:         1
       ACL:                    []
   ```
4. Next, I set another service account, but this time WITHOUT DECRYPT permission and with object viewer permission (so that it be able to read files from the bucket):

   ```
   $ gcloud config set account my-service-account-WITHOUT-DECRYPT-and-with-object-viewer-permissions

   Updated property [core/account].
   ```
5. After set up the new service account (WITHOUT Decrypt permission), the gustil to restore the file from the bucket works smooth...

   ```
   gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/my-file .

   Copying gs://my-bucket/my-file...
   \ [1 files][602.5 KiB/602.5 KiB]                                                
   Operation completed over 1 objects/602.5 KiB.
   ```

My question is whether is it a normal behavior ? Or, since the new service account doesn't have Decrypt permission, the `gustil cp` to restore the file shouldn't work ? I mean, it is not the idea that with KMS encryption, the 2nd `gustil cp` command should fail with a "403 permission denied" error message or something..

If I revoke "Storage object viewer" privilege from the 2nd service account (to restore the file from the bucket), in this case the gustil fails, but it is because it doesn't have permission to read the file:

```
$ gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/my-file . 
AccessDeniedException: 403 my-service-account-WITHOUT-DECRYPT-and-with-object-viewer-permissions does not have storage.objects.list access to my-bucket.
```

I appreciate if someone else could give me a hand, and clarify the question....specifically I don't sure whether the command `gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/my-file .` should work or not.

I think it shouldn't work (because the service account doesn't have Decrypt permission), or should it work ?

Answer (score 1):

This is working correctly. When you use Cloud KMS with Cloud Storage, the data is encrypted and decrypted under the authority of the Cloud Storage service, not under the authority of the entity requesting access to the object. This is why you have to add the Cloud Storage service account to the ACL for your key in order for CMEK to work.

When an encrypted GCS object is accessed, the KMS decrypt permission of the accessor is never used and its presence isn't relevant.

If you don't want the second service account to be able to access the file, remove its read access.

Comment: Thanks Tim. From your response, I think I need to read a little more about Cloud Storage service accounts things. At a glance it seems that I have completed just a 50% of tasks to get the KMS set up done... (according to my use case). The rest of the tasks are probably related to the cloud storage server account and ACL's  permission.  

I think this question can be closed. If I have any other in the near future, I'll open a new issue. 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds good. Feel free to ping if you have any further problems.

Comment: I Agree with José that this is different than expected. But thanks @TimDierks for clarification. In case of CSEK each object within a bucket can be encrypted differently with different key but what is the point when the ACL has to be set at the bucket level. ACL and encryption key both has different role to play but not in this case.

Comment: To be clear, every object is encrypted with a different key (or multiple keys); the KMS key is a key which manages all these object-specific keys. See https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption

Answer (score 0):

By default, Cloud Storage encrypts all object data using Google-managed encryption keys. You can instead provide your own keys. There are two types:

1. CSEK which you must supply
2. CMEK which you also supply, but this time is managed by Google KMS service (this is the one you are using).

When you use `gsutil cp`, you are already using the encryption method behind the curtains. So, as stated on the documentation for [Using Encryption Keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/UsingEncryptionKeys#using-encryption-keys):

> While decrypting a CSEK-encrypted object requires supplying the CSEK
>   in one of the decryption_key attributes, this is not necessary for
>   decrypting CMEK-encrypted objects because the name of the CMEK used to
>   encrypt the object is stored in the object's metadata.

As you can see, the key is not necessary because it is already included on the metadata of the object which is the one the `gsutil` is using.

> If encryption_key is not supplied, gsutil ensures that all data it
>   writes or copies instead uses the destination bucket's default
>   encryption type - if the bucket has a default KMS key set, that CMEK
>   is used for encryption; if not, Google-managed encryption is used.

Comment: Thanks Nahuel. I appreciate your input.